# Inheritance model in Orient Db

Tags: java, inheritance, orientdb

I have a scenario where I have a graph and want to create an inheritance into vertices .

With already specified class:Person node(super class) with specific properties , I am creating subclass and assigning new properties to the subclass specified as under(Here Mysubclass is the subclass for person)

OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph("remote:/localhost/newhilti", "root", "varun");
        graph.createVertexType("Mysubclass", "Person");

```
    Vertex vPerson = graph.addVertex("class:Mysubclass");
    vPerson.setProperty("firstName", "John");
    vPerson.setProperty("lastName", "Smith");
    graph.commit();
```

Now when I try and get the properties of Mysubclass it is not giving me the properties of its superclass ie. Person.

May I please have a clarification if anything is missing here or is it the normal behavior which can't be the case I suppose if we are using inheritance .

Thanks-

Varun Tahin

Answer (score 6):

As Michela wrote in the sample, you should add at least one value for an inherited property in the new vertex vPerson, to see the column in the result set of a select from vPerson; the child class Mysubclass has all the parent properties, together with his own properties, but you will not see the property values in result set when all the values for that property are null. So this is a normal behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 Vertex vPerson = graph.addVertex("class:Mysubclass");
    vPerson.setProperty("firstName", "John");
    vPerson.setProperty("lastName", "Smith");
    vPerson.setProperty("<Person property>", "<value>");
    vPerson.setProperty("<Person property>", "<value>");
    graph.commit();
```

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: I think above is not a proper solution as the child should contain the property keys of the parent and values as null if not specified .

Providing it explicitly for the children will defeat the purpose of inheritance if my understanding is correct.

Thanks-

Varun Tahin